# How can I find all tiles that must be passed to get from one tile to another

Tags: java, algorithm, grid, path-finding

So here is a fun problem I ran into while doing a Nurikabe solver for my final school project.

Let's say I have a grid of n * m tiles on which there are obstacles. Now imagine that I have a starting tile and an ending tile. Moving only horizontally or vertically I need to get from the starting tile to the ending tile. But I don't care about the actual path. All I need is to find the tiles that are passed no matter what path I would to take.

[image: example]

White: passable tiles
Gray: obstacles
S: starting tile
E: ending tile
Green: must-be-passed tiles

Hope this is enough to display what I want. I would really appreciate if you could help me find the best path finding algorithm to use in this situation and how I could most efficiently and easily extract only the must-be-passed tiles.

Comment: StackOverflow is not designed to write software for its users but rather help with code which has a developer stuck. Besides, you'll learn more if you do your own homework.

Comment: You can find all possible paths by using path-finding algorithm such as Depth First Search. After finding all paths you can find the tiles that are included in all of them. 
Alternatively: find the shortest path (by using Breadth-First-Search for example). After fining the path make each tile in the path an obstacle, one tile at a time, and see which block the path meaning no alternative path can be found.

Comment: Alright I'll give that a try, thanks!